# After trying various optimzers, model simplification running more iterations, when fitting GLMMs, R still produces warning messages

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to fit GLMM's to my data using the glmer function available in R's lme4 package.
The data is available at: 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B727FC7180E87DF%21118

I keep getting warning messages. Can anybody help me get rid of them.

Tried fitting the model:
`Food_Treatment.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Food*Treatment+(1|Set),family=binomial,data=data,method = "ML")`

to get the warning messages

```
"Warning messages:

1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.001101 (tol = 0.001, component 3)

2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues"
```

After running code with more iterations of the model, I still get the same warning messages:
`Food_Treatment.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Food*Treatment+(1|Set),data=data,family=binomial,control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))`

I then looked on-line and that people had similar problems and tried the otmizer "bobyqa":

Food_Treatment.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Food*Treatment+(1|Set),data=data,family=binomial,                            control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))

I then got the very similar warning messages:

"Warning messages:

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00393532 (tol = 0.001, component 2)

2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues"
```

I then thought of simplifying the model and tried no interactions between explanatory variables, with the codes:

```
Food.Plus.Treatment.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Food+Treatment+(1|Set),family=binomial,data=data)
```

and

```
Food.Plus.Treatment.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Food+Treatment+(1|Set),family=binomial,data=data,control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))
```

Only to get the warning messages :

```
"Warning messages:

1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00248016 (tol = 0.001, component 2)

2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues"
```

So I tried this simplified model with the opimizers "bobyqa" and "Nelder_Mead", as well as the otimzers "nlminb" and "L-BFGS-B" from the package optimx.

All but the "bobyqa" opimzers produce variations on the 2 warning messages.
"bobyqa" otpimzer produces the 1 warning message:

```
"warning message:

In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00139574 (tol = 0.001, component 2)
```

P.S. This is my first post on here I hope I have provided enough information without being verbose and it is correctly formatted.

Comment: Your problem is you have so few `Virus_DNA==positive` values (N=12) in comparison to the number combinations of co-variates and random effects that your model is just impossible to estimate. You simply do not have enough data to fit such a complex model. You might want to post to [stats.se] instead for possible statistical alternatives to a generalized linear mixed model.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I knew that was likely to be contributing issue if not the main problem. For the reason that the block effect could be argued to be a fixed effect or random effect the data has been analysed with straight glms and produced some (now resolved) problems for the same reason. One thing that did come out with analysing with GLMs is that the data is linearly seperated with all the Virus_DNA==positive being in low food group. Could this be contributing to these warning messages.

Comment: @MrFlick I do not understand how to determine whether my own modeling attempts suffer from the same problem of an over complex model being estimated with too little data. In the context of mixed linear models, where can I learn more, in order to make such an assessment?

Comment: @Muno Sorry. I don't have any specific advice on that. More general stats questions are better asked on [stats.se]. But generally speaking you should have many more observations than parameters you need to estimate.